# Syntax Angular2 Pipe <template>

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to mix the  syntax and the pipes but I couldn't find too many information.

The Pipe I already added on the component by pipes: [SearchPipe], and the SearchPipe I named as "search", here is my try:

```
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="Items | Search: Past" #isHeader="first" >
```

Any help will be helpful. 
Thanks guys

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Angular2 RC than you have to use :-

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="Items | Search: Past" let-isHeader="first" >
```

Comment: but use of `let-` is only for angular2 RC, may be @Rodboc using angular2 beta.

Comment: exactly than you can put it as comment until you are not sure isn't it @Gunter

Comment: I'm using angular Beta, sorry but I can't use let- @PardeepJain. Is there any way to do it in the beta version?

Comment: No that's new RC syntax. So what's the problem with the code in your question? What doesm't work?

Comment: what you are trying to do in the beta version ? whats the problem exactly @rodboc ?

Comment: My Bad, the error was in the pipe, not in the syntax. My apologies

Comment: No prob. Glad to hear you figured it out.